# Mentioning legally PCT in an agreement

Tags: pct

I have a PCT application with a publication number and I would like to know how I can mention my patent "legally" in a business agreement if my patent is not yet entered the "National" stage in any country.

Thank you 
Waheed

Comment: You've referred to "your patent", but you don't have a patent. A PCT application never becomes a patent.

Answer (score 1):

Every PCT application has an application number. If you refer to this, the application is clearly and uniquely identified. For example, "PCT application number PCT/US2016/012345".

The publication isn't really the application, so you probably don't want to refer to the publication number necessarily. Though you could say "the application corresponding to PCT publication number WO 2016/012345", though that's somewhat of an unnecessary circumlocution.